# Please give an algebraic proof of the following inequality: $\frac{a}{a+b} \gt \frac{a-1}{a+b-1}$ for $a,b \gt 0$.

Tags: inequality

For $ a,b > 0 $ and $\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$, show that $$\frac{a}{a+b} > \frac{a-1}{a+b-1}$$

I am not getting how to do this. Please enlighten me. What i need is an algebraic proof.

My thought, let $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+b}$, and $f'(x) = \frac{b}{(x+b)^2}$, this implies $f(x)$ is increasing, i.e, $f(x) > f(x-1)$. But can we solve it simply, I tried solving just using inequalities I can't find how.

Comment: We will help only if you show us what you have tried and your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: My thought, let $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+b}$, and $f'(x) = \frac{b}{(x+b)^2}$, this implies f(x) is increasing, i.e, f(x) > f(x-1). But can we solve it simply, i tried solving just using inequalities i cant find how.

Comment: Fix $b=\frac12$, Then $f(x):=\frac x{x+b}\cdot\frac {x-1}{x+b-1}$ is continuous on $[0,\frac14]$, this varies continuously from $f(0)=0$ to $f(\frac14)=1$, hence $f(a)=\frac13$ fro som e$a$ inbetween. With these $a,b$,we have $\frac a{a+b}-\frac {a-1}{a+b-1}=\frac b{(a+b)(a+b-1)}<0$.

Comment: This is a part of a probability question, here a and b are both integers, actually number of black and white balls and the main question is to find the smallest number of balls given the above condition(given prob getting two white balls on two consecutive draw is 1/3). Its an example question, there its simply given the above inequality, i wanted to solve it just using basic inequality identities/properties.

Comment: You should edit your question to add the assumption that $a$ and $b$ are integers. This makes the other assumption irrelevant. You just cross-multiply and cancel like terms to reduce the inequality to $-a > -a - b$. (The cross-multiplication is valid because $a + b - 1$ is positive if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}=\frac{b}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}
$$
Given that $a,b>0$, your statement is equivalent to $a+b-1>0$.

*If $a$ and $b$ are integer, as you seem to hint in the comments, then the statement is completely obvious.*

For general real $a,b$, we'd like to see whether this follows from
$$
\frac{a}{a+b}\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
It's simpler if we set $a+b=c$, so the equality becomes
$$
3a^2-3a=c^2-c
$$
We'd like to see whether the equation $c^2-c-3a^2+3a=0$ has or not solutions satisfying $a<c<1$, which would prove the conjecture false.

The roots are
$$
\frac{1\pm\sqrt{12a^2-12a+1}}{2}
$$
We have
$$
a<\frac{1-\sqrt{12a^2-12a+1}}{2}
$$
if and only if $1-2a>\sqrt{12a^2-12a+1}$, which reduces to $0<a<(3-\sqrt{6})/6$. In this case, the root is obviously less than $1$.

Suppose $a=0.01$. Then the chosen root is $\approx0.03$ and your conjecture is false.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides by  $\frac{a}{a+b}$ you get because of your hypothesis :

$$\frac{a}{a+b} > \frac{a-1}{a+b-1} \implies (\frac{a}{a+b})^2 > \frac{1}{3} \implies a(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}) >  b\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \implies a>\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}-1}$$

But this is not always the case.